# Creating an instance in GCP VertexAI Workbench with Dataproc and Real-time collaboration is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Recently, I have been facing issues creating instances in GCP VertexAI Workbench with Dataproc and Real-time collaboration enabled.

Dataproc integration should be enabled by default on the instances. But this option is not being respected on creation. And I need to enable it manually.

Regarding Real-time collaboration, I enable this option by adding the metadata key-value pair `use-collaborative: true`. But now, when I try to set it, it is not working.

I think this has started happening since last week.

Is someone else facing the same issue?

I tried enabling Dataproc on creation. But every time I create a new instance, this option is disabled. I need to re-enable it after instance creation.

I added the metadata key-value pair for Real-time collaboration during instance creation and after creation time. And it is not set.

Comment: Delete your post. Please report bugs and feature requests on Google's Issue Tracker. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers StackOverflow is the wrong place to post this type of question/problem.

Comment: For first problem I was able to reproduce. If you click Fast creation Dataproc is not enabled by default, you need to click Advanced Options. I will open a bug for this.

Comment: For Real Time collaboration. You have 2 issues. One is the UI is not setting metadata correctly which is being fixed. The second one is RTC in JupyterLab 3.6 has changed https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#real-time-collaboration you may need to install package manually and test.

Comment: Thank you much @gogasca! I will try it and let you know if the RTC works. And thank you for open a bug for the other issue!

Comment: Existing implementation for `use-collaborative` uses `c.LabApp.collaborative = True` so this may not work anymore in JL 3.6